# Understanding a certain JS script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a challange and i got to this script:

```
<script>
function r(){
for(var r=0,e=0,a="",l=0;l<n.length;l++)
    if(n[l].toLowerCase()!=n[l]&&(r+=1),8==++e){
        if(!t)
        return;
        a+=String.fromCharCode(r),r=0,e=0
        } else r<<=1;return a
}
var e=!1,t=!1,a=setInterval(function(){
    e&&(t=!0,alert("Your flag is: "+r()),clearInterval(a));t=!1
    },1e3)
    ,n="kACgqAPgqVQbTCycnTVmofqPnOKzvBSPhLAHYtUFsBwykxefnUhiJPdugBmkHCqwrFqDAVPIjJtSShzOnyVAnwkefSZJqXmIfWPWanLtpYeFKJHRuNZgbrWsiAyjsvemyOQSiqFEsiMUraVJfQvWGNWPuSIpjpnBpHYDvoMufeHRfaPWwMrZJJWMgHvlnzTmdPDamBoDfPnpYNtrmmDPjunyxAWvSWZdrQyarFXWhCfYNQMNsxGZoWPXjEUoMAMIuXtGJDWKgPbYlMrCxBBCkhZOiKFSAQvS";
</script>
```

it says "Your flag is: ...."
and i am trying to executing the code in a way that will show me the intended alert but i dont seem to find a way to initiate the setinterval to see the alert.

any ideas?

Comment: usually just execute it, but the code is wrong and will throw multiple syntax errs...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are  you posting obviously minimized code? Where did you lift if from?

Comment: The challange is an html page with a gif base64 which i believe was ment to throw me off and try to find the text inside the gif.
after looking at the source code i found the script and it clearly says about "Your flag is here..."
so it became an understading question of the script.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qozumopaju/edit?js

Comment: Great thanks! i've been trying to run it for hours

Comment: @silvercr youre welcome. Please tick the green button underneath ;)

Comment: For new users it takes time for the upvote to be visible

Answer (score 0):

The formatted code:

```
function r(){
    var r=0,e=0,a="";
    for(l=0;l<n.length;l++){
        if(n[l]!=n[l].toLowerCase()){
            r++;
        }
        e++;
        if(8==e){
           a+=String.fromCharCode(r);
           r=0,e=0;
        } else {
           r<<=1;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/temuqosayo/edit?console

So you have to read it in 8 char blocks and then convert it:

```
"kACgqAPg" //=> one char
```

So every big letter increases it by 1, and every iteration from left to right does a leftshift, wich is equal to *2. So in fact, every small letter is a 0, and every big one a 1:

```
"kACgqAPg" 
 01100110
```

wich is then converted to a char "f" and so on. So your code could also look like this:

```
var solution=
n.split("").map(el=>el!=el.toLowerCase()?"1":"0")//small letters=0, big letters=1
.reduce((str,el,i)=>str+el+(!((i+1)%8)?",":""),"").split(",")//group in 8 char strings
.reduce((str,el)=>str+String.fromCharCode(parseInt(el,2),"") //convert one group to its char
```

http://jsbin.com/rahokinepi/edit?console